# Angular 1.5 Scope Variable not working from within PouchDB response function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, single-page-application, pouchdb

So I've got the following code...

```
testApp.controller(...) {

    $scope.results = [];
    $scope.hasData = true;

    $scope.results.push({
        "name": "test"
    }); // WORKS

    db.get('table_people').then(function(response) {
        console.log('success');

        $scope.results.push({
            "name": "test"
        });
    }); // this DOESN'T WORK even though the "success" message is printed...

});
```

And as you can tell from the comments, the first `push` to the array works, but the latter one doesn't. Top one can be printed out in the Angular template using `{{ results }}` but the latter one returns an empty array.

**Edit:** A solution has been found by using `$timeout` as the *digest cycle* wasn't running but sort of feels like a hacked together solution.

**Edit:** Solution...

```
db.get('table_people').then(function (response) {
    console.log('success');
    $timeout(function () {
        $scope.results = response.data;
    });
});
```

The solution code is slightly different as I no longer need the test data anymore due to the code functioning and can apply the response data directly.

Comment: What happens when you console.log($scope) from inside the nested function?  Maybe $scope is actually out of scope - no pun intended.

Comment: Post the solution too.  Maybe it can be tidied up.

Comment: Or, maybe just force a digest cycle.

Comment: I read this article a while back.  https://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-angulars-apply-digest/  Helped me with a $digest issue or two.

Comment: Solution added @TarekAdam and thanks for the link, I'm not sure if it would apply to this use case but may be helpful for the future :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing a `$digest` cycle tick. Doing `$scope.$digest()` after you've pushed the data into `$scope.results` should fix the issue. Using `$timeout` is a bit of an overkill in this situation (and additional service to inject).

Comment: Ah, an even better solution! Thank you kind sir :)